# Very Slow tmpfs Read/Write speeds

Tags: centos, vps, tmpfs

I have attempted to use a tmpfs to speed up some heavily accessed files. I wanted to test the read and write speeds of both the HDD its self and a tmpfs. My results where strangely low for what I was expecting: 
`dd if=/dev/zero of=/home/******/tmpfs/test.data bs=1k count=128k
131072+0 records in
131072+0 records out
134217728 bytes (134 MB) copied, 4.03752 seconds, 33.2 MB/s`

The directory `/home/******/tmpfs` is a 200MB tmpfs that I mounted a little bit before.

I do not have much experience with tmpfs's and was wondering... Isn't this very slow? What can be done to speed this up? What is causing the slow speeds?

Answer (score 1):

That speed is suspiciously close to the speed of a somewhat slow hard drive. You may have run out of real memory and started swapping. How much free memory do you have?

Comment: `free -m` outputs: 1884 used (2043 total) 946 cache (1097 buffers)

Comment: The contents of tmpfs will contribute to that value in cache.  What is the output of "swapon -s"